# How to implement comments through firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement comments on feedMessages through firebase database, but do not know how to implement the uploading/downloading procedure in code. If I want my database to look like the image shown how can I upload/download those comments on the messages?

```
func getFeedMessages(handler: @escaping (_ feedMessages:[FeedMessages]) -> ()){
        var feedMessagesArray = [FeedMessages]()
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (feedMessagesSnapshot) in
            guard let feedMessagesSnapshot = feedMessagesSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

            for messages in feedMessagesSnapshot {
                let content = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String ?? "Joe Flacco is an elite QB"
                let icon = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "icon").value as? String ?? "none"
                let color = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "color").value as? String ?? "bop"

                let messages = FeedMessages(content: content, color: color, icon: icon, votes: votes)
                feedMessagesArray.append(messages)
            }
            handler(feedMessagesArray)
        }
    }




 func uploadMessage(withContent content: String, withIcon icon: String, withColor color: String,sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()){
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["content" : content, "color" : color, "icon" : icon)
        sendComplete(true)
    }
```

[desired Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/156PT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're super close! The comments node is really just a child snapshot within each message node so you can treat it as such.

Here's your code with the extra code to print the comments from each message node.

You'll need to add error checking and the code to add them to the FeedMessages.

```
feedMessagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { feedMessagesSnapshot in
    guard let feedMessagesSnapshot = feedMessagesSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

    for messages in feedMessagesSnapshot {
        let content = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String ?? "Joe Flacco is an elite QB"
        let icon = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "icon").value as? String ?? "none"
        let color = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "color").value as? String ?? "bop"

        print(content, color, icon)

        let comments = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments")
        for comment in comments.children {
            let commentSnap = comment as! DataSnapshot
            let aComment = commentSnap.value as! String
            print(aComment)
        }


        let messages = FeedMessages(content: content, color: color, icon: icon, votes: votes)
        feedMessagesArray.append(messages)
    }
}
```

Writing the node is the same thought process - the comments node is just a another key: value pair within the message, with the value being a set of key: value pairs.

Here's an example where we're using a dictionary to build the structure and then write the node

```
let feedMessagesRef = self.ref.child("feedMessages")

let messageDict:[String: Any] = [
    "content": "some content",
    "color": "some color",
    "icon": "an icon",
    "comments":
        ["comment_0": "a comment",
         "comment_1": "another comment"]
]

let aFeedMessage = feedMessagesRef.childByAutoId()
aFeedMessage.updateChildValues(messageDict)
```